# How to disable a button until the video is uploaded?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have one form in that I want to upload image and video and have to fill some info. Until complete form the submit button is disabled and after complete of video and image upload and all the fields are filled it has to be enable.

```
$("#uploadify").uploadify({
  height        : 30,
  swf           : urljs+'/public/js/uploadify.swf',
  uploader      : urljs+'/public/js/uploadify.php',
  folder        : "../../../uploads",
  width         : 120,
  fileSizeLimit : '200000KB',
  fileTypeDesc  : 'Video Files',
  fileTypeExts  : '*.*;',
  formData      : {
     folder : '../../private/<?php echo $userId;?>'
  },
  onUploadSuccess : function(file, data, response) {
      $("[name=coursebanner]").val(file.name);
      $("[name=banner]").attr("src",'<?php echo base_url();?>private/<?php echo $userId;?>/'+file.name);
  }
});
$(".filedtls").hide();
$("#contentupload").uploadify({
    height        : 30,
    swf           : urljs+'/public/js/uploadify.swf',
    uploader      : urljs+'/public/js/uploadify.php',
    folder        : "../../../uploads",
    width         : 120,
    fileSizeLimit : '40MB', 
    fileTypeDesc  : 'Video Files',
    fileTypeExts  : '*.*;',
    formData      : {
       folder : '../../private/<?php echo $userId;?>/beforeconvert',
       folder1 : '../../private/<?php echo $userId;?>',
       userId : <?php echo $userId?>
    },
    'onComplete': function(event, queueID, fileObj, response, data) {       
   console.log(response);
 },
 'onUploadSuccess' : function(file, data, response) {
        $("[name=promovideoname]").val(file.name);
    }
  });


   $('#createcoursebasicform > input').keyup(function() {

    var empty = false;
    $('#createcoursebasicform > input').each(function() {
        if ($(this).val() == '') {
            empty = true;
        }
    });

    if (empty) {
        $('#save').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    } else {
        $('#save').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
});
```

and

```
<div class="col-md-9">
    <form id="createcoursebasicform">
      <input type="hidden" name="courseId" value="<?php echo $courseId;?>"/>
          <div class="create-course-content">

             <!-- COURSE BANNER -->
              <div class="course-banner create-item">
                 <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                      <h4>Course Banner</h4>
                     </div>
                     <div class="col-md-9">
                        <div class="image-info">
                        <img name="banner" src="<?php echo base_url();?>public/images/placeholder.jpg" alt="">
                         </div>
                         <input type="hidden" name="coursebanner"/>
                         <div class="upload-recrop">
                           <div class="upload-image up-file" id="uploader">
                              <a href="#"><i class="icon md-upload"></i><div id="uploadify"></div></a>
                           </div>

                         </div>
                      </div>
                   </div>
                </div>
            <!-- END / COURSE BANNER -->
            <!-- PROMO VIDEO -->
             <div class="promo-video create-item">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                      <h4>Promo Video</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-9">
                      <div class="form-item">
                         <input type="text" placeholder="Paste URL">
                      </div>
                      <div class="upload-video up-file">
                                    or
                       <a href="#"><i class="icon md-upload"></i><div id="contentupload"></div></a>

                        <input type="hidden" name="promovideoname">
                      </div>
                    </div>
                 </div>
               </div>

              <div class="duration create-item">
                  <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-md-3">
                         <h4>Duration</h4>
                       </div>
                       <div class="col-md-9">
                          <div class="duration-ct">
                             <div class="form-item">
                                <input type="text" name="duration">
                             </div>
                             <span class="day">days</span>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-action">
                    <input id="save" type="submit" value="Save and Next" class="submit mc-btn-3 btn-style-1" disabled="disabled">
                  </div>
               </form>
           </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I always use JavaScript to disable and enable a submit button.

**HTML**

```
<input type="submit" id="switch" value="xxxx" disabled="disabled" />
```

You might want to pass a flag after the uploading is completed. Say `Finish`,  and put it in a Json, then you could use AJAX to get the `Finish` from the server.

JavaScript

```
 $.ajax({
  url: "test.php",
  dataType: "json", 
  success: function(data){ 
    data.Finish ? $switch.attr('disabled', true) : $switch.removeAttr('disabled');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery with Ajax call for your submit and use :

```
 beforeSend
```

to disable the submit button !

Comment: I have updated my question and I am tried like that but its not working. Is there any wrong.

Comment: `$('#createcoursebasicform > input').keyup(function() {

    var empty = false;
    $('#createcoursebasicform > input').each(function() {
        if ($(this).val() == '') {
            empty = true;
        }
    });

    if (empty) {
        $('#save').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    } else {
        $('#save').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
});`

Comment: And what is the problem ?

Comment: I solved it like adding ` <input id="switch" type="submit" value="Save and Next" class="submit mc-btn-3 btn-style-1" disabled="disabled" style="cursor:not-allowed">` and in `onUploadsuccess  $("#switch").attr("disabled", false);` It will working at the time of first video uploading time. I want to disable that while uploading second video means multi video upload.

Comment: So you should either upload all videos together or run your jQuery again for validating !

Comment: I want to run jQuery again for validating

Answer (score 0):

When you get $_post or $_get request from user use below html code to disable button

```
 <input type="Submit" value="Upload" <?php echo $disable; ?> />
```

value of $disable out from if($_post) or get statement is NUll or ''. in if condition use $disable = 'disabled';

Upload all your file and data, when you have reached EOF make $disable=Null.